# Pass parameter to twig view in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, twig

I have a twig page which I included a `picture` , this picture will be loaded from a `folder` (`uploads`) , but the name (`example.jpg`) is loaded from the `database` :

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/example1.jpg') }}">
```

this works for me , but I want now that `example1.jpg`  will be passed to the `twig` page :

```
return $this->render('MyAppExampleBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
            'logo' => $logo)); //$logo = 'example1.jpg'
```

How I can do this?

I  have tried  `<img src="{{ asset('uploads/{{logo}}') }}">`  but this is illogic and doesn't work .

Any help plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about,

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/' ~ logo) }}">
```

`{{ ... }}` twig delimiters can't be nested. You should then use concatenation.

Comment: This works if the *uploads* folder is in web path of Symfony. How about if the `uploads` folder be in a different path in system (not in Symfony web path)

Comment: @Javad you should then reconsider the way you're building your assets within your templates.

Answer (score 1):

try `{{ asset('uploads/' ~ logo) }}`